# Adding a TextInputLayout breaks the Android Studio layout preview, but the apk builds as expected and the app runs without issues

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, material-ui

I am trying to make a Material3 application with Android Studio.
I was able to successfully add a `MaterialButton` but when adding a `TextInputLayout`, the preview fails without even showing an error.

This is the snippet that works without issues:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/mybtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/open"/>
```

This is the xml snippet that causes the issue:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="ok">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My project is brand new and created using the latest Android Studio version (2022.1.1 patch 1)

[This is a GIF of the issue](https://ibb.co/qjzNN5j)

I tried:

- Completely uninstalling Android Studio, the Android SDK and all gradle, caches and configuration files and then reinstalled everything
- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Using the Android Studio Material 3 Activity project template
- Checking for issues in the gradle files (missing dependencies, dependencies versions...)

My `build.gradle` (project)

```c
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

My `build.gradle` (Module app) dependencies:

```c
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

My `settings.gradle`:

```c
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "MyMood"
include ':app'
```

I am using the Material3 styles:

- Light: `<style name="Theme.MyMood" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">`
- Dark: `<style name="Theme.MyMood" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, Electric Eel + Material3 Theme + TextInputLayout brakes layout preview.

This used to work fine before upgrading to Electric Eel, and at the moment, I think downgrading Android Studio is the only option.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i was really losing my mind over it. I hope it will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and waslosing my mind over it as well! However I made it work now with `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`

- Update Android Studio to Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
- Update Material Design to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha02'`
- Update Plugins to `id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false` and `id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false`

Afterwards clean the project and invalidate ALL caches under: File -> Invalidate Caches (MacOS)
After Android Studio restarted Rebuild Project and then it should work.

Comment: Thank you. i was already using the Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar but was on Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1. Updating to Patch 2 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, **what I did** was

- Uninstalled my Android Studio, and
- Removed the **.gradle** folder from **C:\Users\UserName**,
- Removed the **Android** folder and **Android Open Source** folder from
  **C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local**,
- Removed the **AndroidStudio** folders from
  **C:\Users\ya922\AppData\Local\Google**, and
- Removed the **Android** folder from **C:\Program Files\Android**
- and then installed the same version which is **Android Studio
  Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2**, which is also the latest stable build as of now

after setting up everything, I created a new project to check if the problem was still there, but everything was working well!

I inspected the projects I made earlier, and found that the problem was still there and upon comparing the **build.gradle** of both the projects I found that there were few differences between their **dependencies**, so I copied those from the new project to the old one and its been working fine since then.

**I would strongly suggest updating these two dependencies**:

1. `implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")`
2. `implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")`

Note*: I am using **Windows 11 ver 23H2 Home Single Language**

My build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
}
```

My build.gradle(module)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.splashscreen"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.splashscreen"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

My settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Splash Screen"
include(":app")
```

Answer (score 0):

well i reproduced your code in the newest version of Android Studios ( Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 ) and the xml showed just fine.

I did have issues reproducing the xml myself back in the previous version ( Dolphin ) but i guess its fixed now.
Try updating android studio to the newest version.

If that doesn't work try changing an option in your " design screen " called "Theme for Preview "

Comment: I am currently on 2022.1.1 patch 1. I tried changing the theme and it works fine if i change `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`. However i need Material3 theme and i have no idea how to fix that.